# PHP download page: file_exists() returns true, but browser returns 'page not found'

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, download

I'm using PHP for a file download page. Here's a snippet of the problem code:

```
if (file_exists($attachment_location)) {
    header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . " 200 OK");
    header("Cache-Control: public"); // needed for i.e.
    header("Content-Type: application/zip");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
    header("Content-Length:".filesize($attachment_location));
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.zip");
    readfile($attachment_location);  
    die("Hooray");   
}
else {
    die("Error: File not found.");
}
```

This code works absolutely fine when testing locally, but after deploying to the live server the browser returns a 'Page not found' error. I thought it might be an .htaccess issue, but all .htaccess files on the live server are identical to their local counterparts. My next guess would be the live server's PHP configuration, but I have no idea what PHP setting might cause this behaviour.

The file_exists() function always returns true - I've checked this on the live server and it's always correctly picking up the file, its size etc., so it does have a handle on the file. It just won't perform the download!

The main site is a Wordpress site, but this code isn't part of a Wordpress page - it's in a standalone directory within the site root.

UPDATE: is_file() and is_readable() are both returning true for the file, so that's not the problem. The specific line that is causing the problem is:

```
readfile($attachment_location)
```

Everything up until that point is super happy.

Comment: Try to echo the filepath and see if there's anything fishy

Comment: Maybe in your Live Server you have configured your apache sites-available config, denying access for user. PHP might be able to see the file, but not the user.

Comment: if file_exists() always returns true, then it's not possible for the "else" code path to execute.

Comment: The file path looks good. I'll look into the sites-available config in apache. And file_exists always returning true is not a problem - I don't want the 'else' code path to execute anyway! I just wanted to point out that the problem didn't seem to be with the file getting picked up.

Comment: I guess the additional underscore is just a typo?

Comment: Are you sure the rest of your script is executing? If the browser returns `Page not found`, the problem is most likely with the link to your page.

Comment: Well spotted with the typo! I'll remove the extra underscore, thanks. The rest of the script is definitely executing - I've tested every stage of this fastidiously and it's just the readfile line that is causing things to go awry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out to be a filesize problem. The file in question was pretty huge (over 300MB) - I tried replacing it with a smaller file (~1MB) and everything's working as expected. The next hurdle is to try to get the server to deal with the large file! Thanks everyone for your help.

EDIT: There's a lot of discussion about the limits of the readfile function and how to circumvent them on the [readfile function page at php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)

Answer (score 4):

Just because a file exists doesn't mean you can serve it.  It might have the wrong permissions, or be locked while something else writes to it, it might not even be a file at all.  The file_exists function returns true for directories, symlinks and so on.

You might want to look at using is_file instead.  Also you might want to look at is_readable for file permission checking.

Comment: Thank you - I'll try is_file and is_readable and report back. The file permissions are set to 644 - I thought this would be sufficient but will try 777 just to be 100% sure

Comment: Ok - is_file and is_readable are both returning true. I've also set the permissions to 777 and still no luck! Thanks for your help though